# (0, _reactNativeCodePush2.default) is not a function error in React native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm building a react native project and I got this error on running.
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please give some clues about what you've already done with your codes. We can't do anything if you just only shows the error message like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it following steps below.

1. Create account on code-push(microsoft.github.io/code-push) and register into collaborator on existing app.
2. Run `code-push app ls` on terminal and see if registered successfully.
3. Run `code-push deployment ls "appname" -k` on terminal to get deployment keys.
4. `Run react-native link` and enter the keys on prompt.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me because I ran `react-native run-ios` immediately after installing code-push.  It turns out that I needed to run `pod install` in my ios directory, then clean and rebuild to make this work.

Comment: this helped me and I would add bit clarity on 
1. Go to `cd ios` directory first and then do the `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue as described in this problem. I tried both answers, but neither worked. After being stuck by a `codePush undefined` problem, I figured out that it's my fault. I missed a important step in [CodePush readme tutorial](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push): [iOS setup](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md):

After `pod install` and updating `info.list`, `undefined codePush` disappeared and everything worked well.